# Is there a way to keep a tribe from being empty when all members transfer to another server?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

My daughter and I play ark together.

We play on private dedicated servers hosted on my own machines, nothing online, full admin control.  We have 2 computers and 2 steam accounts.  We have a set of servers set up for all the different maps using ASM and would like to be able to transfer between them at will.

Problem is, if we both transfer out of a server, and then come back later, all our dinos and buildings are no longer ours.  Now I know of a few workarounds, but it gets tedious to go around and take control of every dino and structure every time we transfer around.  Turning all creatures and structures to individual control, tribe use is an option, but A) doesn't solve the problem and B) only works on new stuff.

Is there a way to keep a tribe alive when we both transfer out of it?

Ideally we could create a dummy character that could join the tribe on each server and just stays put.  Doesn't even need to be associated with an account or anything.

Again, we have full file access and server control so any hacky or mod way to fix it can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the [TakeTribe](https://ark.gamepedia.com/Console_commands#TakeTribe) console command?